# Can the bleed-off fuel in an open expander cycle be substituted for another liquid?

Tags: engine-design, design-alternative, power-cycle

In all expander cycles, fuel is used as the working fluid to generate the pressure difference necessary to drive the pumps. This makes sense in a closed expander cycle as it'll eventually be used in combustion, but with an open expander cycle, this is not the case. My question is, would it make more sense to use a more optimised working fluid with a larger difference between liquid density and gas density or higher heat transfer? What sort of performance/reduction of mass could be achieved? would this help in cooling(most open expander cycles introduce the fuel back into the nozzle in film/curtain cooling-inert gasses could aid this)?

Comment: Are you suggesting using a third fluid rather than the fuel or oxidizer?

Comment: @OrganicMarble that was the idea it would come with the complexity of another pump/pressure vessel and the need to precisely meter it throughout the flight- could be worth the performance gain-if there is any to be had

Comment: How interesting... so there'd be a closed pump-driving/chamber-cooling fluid system?

Comment: Reaction Engines' SABRE engine design uses helium as a working fluid, but that's in a closed loop.

Comment: @JCRM do you know how the helium is cooled down?

Comment: yes @ReubenFarley-Hall, the heat is dumped into the fuel (LH2), and while the heat source is the intake air this is topped up with a preburner. The reason for using helium is to avoid problems with hydrogen embrittlement, I don't know if it's more appropriate for turbines.

Comment: Other Alan Bond designs use lithium as a working fluid

Comment: The V2 rockets used hydrogen peroxide mixed with a catalyst to generate steam to drive the turbopump, while it was fueled with alcohol and liquid oxygen. If that's what you mean, then sure, it could be and has been done. But rocket fuel is pretty high-performance stuff -- you generally use only part of its energy in the turbopump to avoid overheating it.

Comment: @Greg it's quite similar to my question but instead of using combustion, like in a gas generator, it would just use the heat of the combustion chamber/nozzle, like in an open expander cycle